# How to create BKS file from CRT in 2019 with windows 10

Tags: android, ssl

I want to pin the ssl with bks file. but I dont know how to do that. My concern is prevent any man in the middle to see the api calls for my android app. I know that I need to pin the ssl. One way is using retrofit. (and it is too easy)

```
CertificatePinner certPinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("appmattus.com",
          "sha256/4hw5tz+scE+TW+mlai5YipDfFWn1dqvfLG+nU7tq1V8=")
    .build();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(certPinner)
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://appmattus.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();
```

also getting sha256 key from any web site is just tooooo easy using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze
And I dont understand how this way improve security. So I decided to use pining BKS file into the app. but this is too hard.

I know I should create BKS file and embed it in android app for ssl pinning. But I couldnt understand how to create that BKS file in windows 10. I have found very few info about creating BKS and they are too old to find android keytool or jre in windows. here is just one old example
http://transoceanic.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-import-ssl-certificate-and-use.html
I am stuk and I need your help. thanks in advance

Comment: Why bother with cryptic command-line commands when there is a simple UI that even allows to directly create BKS v1/v2 files: https://keystore-explorer.org (GPL)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Obtain your Public Key certificate**

To obtain your public key you can ask your security guy in your company or you can easily go to your endpoint (api.sample.com or sample.com, wherever you want to do SSL pinning) from your browser and click on the green lock icon > certificate.

[image]

Then drag and drop certificate icon to your desktop. Done. You have a public certificate.

**Step 2: Create a BKS file**

You need to download bouncy castle jar to create BKS file. The bouncy castle is a crypto API. You can download the latest release from [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Now you can create your BKS file using keytool and bouncy castle provider.

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "[YOUR_PUBLIC_CERTIFICATE_PATH]" -alias [YOUR_ALIAS] -keystore "[BKS_TARGET_PATH]" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "[BOUNCY_CASTLE_JAR_PATH]" -storetype BKS -storepass [YOUR_PASSWORD]
```

For example:-

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "/user/mert/testcertificate.cer" -alias mytestalias -keystore "/user/mert/desktop/certificate.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "/user/mert/bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mypassword
```

> This command will create a BKS file with your public certificate. If
>   you want to add multiple certificates, run this command with your
>   another public certificate. This command will check the target path
>   and add the new certificate to the existing BKS file so that BKS file
>   will have both certificates inside.

Let’s add multiple certificates to the same BKS file.

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "/user/mert/testcertificate.cer" -alias mytestalias -keystore "/user/mert/desktop/certificate.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "/user/mert/bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mypassword

keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "/user/mert/testcertificate2.cer" -alias mytestalias2 -keystore "/user/mert/desktop/certificate.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "/user/mert/bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mypassword
```

As you may see I run the same command and keytool will add another certificate into the same BKS file. But be aware that you should use the different alias name for certificates.

Let’s check if the BKS file really has 2 certificates. To list certificates in your BKS file, you need to run following command

```
keytool -list -keystore "/user/mert/desktop/certificate.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "/user/mert/bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mypassword
```

It will show you the public certificates inside BKS file.

[image]

We have successfully created a BKS file which contains 2 different public key.

So If you have 2 different endpoints in your app and endpoints doesn’t have the same public key, you can use multiple certificates to do SSL pinning in your app.

Step 3: Apply SSL pinning to OkHttp Client
I created a helper class for ssl pinning. This class takes 3 arguments.

- Context
- BKS file
- BKS password (which you type in the command line)

you can find the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/iammert/a61042c45ee1d52c60ce7936ddc1e981#file-rawcertificatepinner-java)

You need to locate your BKS file under your res/raw/ folder.

Almost done. All you need is attaching this SSL pinner to your okhttp client.

```
RawCertificatePinner pinner = new RawCertificatePinner(context, R.raw.mycertificate, 
 "mypassword");
 OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
 builder = rawCertificatePinner.pinCertificate(builder);
 return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(builder.build())
        ...
        .build();
```